# CMake "Cannot specify sources for target PROJECT_NAME which is not built by this project."

Tags: cmake

I am learning CMake but unfortunately most examples are either too simple, too complicated or the folder structure is different to what I'm designing.

I am getting an error but first I will explain the folder structure (please do critique):

```
MyProject
    bin
    build
    src
        ComponentA
            ObjectA.cpp
            CMakeLists.txt
        ComponentB
            ObjectB.cpp
            CMakeLists.txt
        CMakeLists.txt
        main.cpp
    CMakeLists.txt
```

I would like to be able to include some files using their absolute path, for example `main.cpp` might look like this:

```
#include <ComponentB/ObjectB.h>

int main()
{
    ComponentB cb(1, 2, 3);
}
```

but within a source file I'd like to include it's header using the relative path:

```
#include <ComponentB.h>

ComponentB::ComponentB(int a, int b, int c) : _ca(a, b){}
```

(if this causes problems I can include using absolute paths)

My CMakeLists files look like:

`MyProject/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`MyProject/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_ROOT_DIR}/bin)
add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(ComponentA)
add_subdirectory(ComponentB)
```

`MyProject/src/ComponentA/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_sources(MyProject PUBLIC ComponentA.cpp)
```

`MyProject/src/ComponentB/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_sources(MyProject PUBLIC ComponentB.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyProject PUBLIC ComponentA)
```

However when I do:

```
cd build
cmake ..
```

I get this this error:

```
CMake Error at src/ComponentA/CMakeLists.txt:2 (target_sources):
  Cannot specify sources for target "MyProject" which is not built by
  this project.

CMake Error at src/ComponentB/CMakeLists.txt:2 (target_sources):
  Cannot specify sources for target "MyProject" which is not built by
  this project.

CMake Error at src/ComponentB/CMakeLists.txt:3 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "MyProject" which is not
  built by this project.
```

Comment: `CMAKE_ROOT_DIR` isn't a thing, so you're trying to use `/bin` as your output directory.

Comment: @AlexReinking As in change that path to just `/bin`?

Comment: Use a variable that CMake actually defines, like `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, and set the runtime output directory at the top-level as a cache variable. As a rule, don't force the values of `CMAKE_*` variables, simply override their defaults via `set(CACHE)` or, better yet, put them in a preset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability for `target_sources` to add source files via relative path to a target in a different directory was added in CMake 3.13. Since you have specified a minimum version of 3.9.1, this will simply not work.

The policy in question is CMP0076, [which is documented as follows](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0076.html):

> New in version 3.13.
>
> The `target_sources()` command converts relative paths to absolute.
>
> In CMake 3.13 and above, the `target_sources()` command now converts relative source file paths to absolute paths in the following cases:
>
> - Source files are added to the target's `INTERFACE_SOURCES` property.
> - The target's `SOURCE_DIR` property differs from `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`.

It is the second bullet point that applies here.

***You really ought to use a newer version of CMake.*** Anything more than a few versions behind the newest (3.23) is plain masochism.

Comment: Apologies but the version line was copied from an example. I am using version 3.22.1. Does this affect your answer?

Comment: @user997112 - It does not affect my answer because the `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)` statement disables CMP0076 for backwards compatibility. I was not able to reproduce your issue with the latest CMake and policy settings.

Comment: So if I change the minimum version to the version I have, it should work? (ignoring the binary path issue)

Comment: @user997112 - It worked for me, judging by the commands I saw in a dry-run, verbose build.

Comment: I also notice I get `/build/src/` being created. Is this necessary/avoidable?

Comment: @user997112 - I don't see how that's relevant to this Q/A pair. Do you want to ask a new SO question? (But no, it is not avoidable)

Comment: The error message ("Cannot specify sources for target which is not built by this project") has nothing common with relative/absolute paths in `target_sources`. Also, there is similar error message about `target_include_directories` command.